# Update excel sheet through parsing data from angular

Tags: angularjs, angular

I have a question.

I am fetching some data from a website now what I want to do is to write that data in excel through angular and export it, now again when I want more data the file should be updated.

is there any library does that?

Answer (score 0):

I did same thing in my project, but you have to pass your data or file from angular to server side (.Net )and then using any library, you can write in excel easily.

Thanks.